# how to transaction from a KT1 address to another KT1 address?

Tags: transfer, kt1

I am using `multisig.liq` at Try-Liquidity to generate a KT1 address(which has 3 owners, need 2 agree) and I send 10 xtz to it. When I transfer 2 to another KT1 address, I got `../preapply/operations failed`.

I made sure transfer's param "parameters" is right(I paid and transfered 2 xtz to a tz1 address, then I found the block that include pay or manage transaction to get "parameters").

For pay is:

```
'parameters': {
    'prim': 'Left',
    'args': [{
        'prim': 'Unit'
    }]
}
```

For manage is:

```
'parameters': {
    'prim': 'Right',
    'args': [{
        'prim': 'Some',
        'args': [{
            'prim': 'Pair',
            'args': [{
                'string': $destination
            }, {
                'int': $amount

            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

So I want to transfer to another KT1 address. First, I forged operation. Here's the code:

```
header2 = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Cache-Control": "no-cache"}
branch = requests.get("https://alphanet.tezrpc.me/chains/main/blocks/head/hash",headers=header1)
counter = requests.get("https://alphanet.tezrpc.me/chains/main/blocks/head/context/contracts/tz1PvVPHCtyvwrpLKoCFBXbiPh3DwmiFFKnQ/counter",headers=header1)
print(branch.json())
print(counter.json())

body = {'contents': [{
 'kind': 'transaction',
 'amount': '0',
 'source': 'tz1PvVPHCtyvwrpLKoCFBXbiPh3DwmiFFKnQ',
 'destination': 'KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4',
 'storage_limit': '60000',
 'gas_limit': '400000',
'fee': '50000',
'counter': str(int(counter.json()) + 1),
            'parameters': {
                'prim': 'Right',
                'args': [{
                    'prim': 'Some',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'Pair',
                        'args': [{
                            'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                        }, {
                            'int': '2000000'
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
 }],
 'branch': branch.json()
}
r = requests.post("https://alphanet.tezrpc.me/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge/operations",json = body,headers=header2)
print(r.json())

result is ok,return:    iaee37aa2db362fd021d14d669e7f34df15216e98714d31d4ecccc4c6bcdc11b10800002efd70b3ca5eb8d39531d36aa1b4eea21d52e8a0d08603c76880b518e0d403000133f2e99faa15741f833d623aa99800701aa2036900ff0000003405080509070701000000244b543143593467354d547877796643377a5435656a7538466b64676d6e4767484635516a008092f401
```

This is when `../preapply/operations failed` happens. Here is the result:

```
'contents': [{
    'kind': 'transaction',
    'source': 'tz1PvVPHCtyvwrpLKoCFBXbiPh3DwmiFFKnQ',
    'fee': '50000',
    'counter': '13383',
    'gas_limit': '400000',
    'storage_limit': '60000',
    'amount': '0',
    'destination': 'KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4',
    'parameters': {
        'prim': 'Right',
        'args': [{
            'prim': 'Some',
            'args': [{
                'prim': 'Pair',
                'args': [{
                    'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                }, {
                    'int': '2000000'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    },
    'metadata': {
        'balance_updates': [{
            'kind': 'contract',
            'contract': 'tz1PvVPHCtyvwrpLKoCFBXbiPh3DwmiFFKnQ',
            'change': '-50000'
        }, {
            'kind': 'freezer',
            'category': 'fees',
            'delegate': 'tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU',
            'level': 104,
            'change': '50000'
        }],
        'operation_result': {
            'status': 'failed',
            'errors': [{
                'kind': 'permanent',
                'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.badContractParameter',
                'contract': 'KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4'
            }, {
                'kind': 'permanent',
                'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError',
                'location': 0,
                'expectedType': {
                    'prim': 'or',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'unit',
                        'annots': ['%_Liq_entry_pay']
                    }, {
                        'prim': 'option',
                        'args': [{
                            'prim': 'pair',
                            'args': [{
                                'prim': 'key_hash',
                                'annots': ['%destination']
                            }, {
                                'prim': 'mutez',
                                'annots': ['%amount']
                            }],
                            'annots': [':proposition']
                        }],
                        'annots': ['%_Liq_entry_manage']
                    }],
                    'annots': [':_entries']
                },
                'wrongExpression': {
                    'prim': 'Right',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'Some',
                        'args': [{
                            'prim': 'Pair',
                            'args': [{
                                'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                            }, {
                                'int': '2000000'
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                'kind': 'permanent',
                'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError',
                'location': 1,
                'expectedType': {
                    'prim': 'option',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'pair',
                        'args': [{
                            'prim': 'key_hash',
                            'annots': ['%destination']
                        }, {
                            'prim': 'mutez',
                            'annots': ['%amount']
                        }],
                        'annots': [':proposition']
                    }]
                },
                'wrongExpression': {
                    'prim': 'Some',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'Pair',
                        'args': [{
                            'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                        }, {
                            'int': '2000000'
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                'kind': 'permanent',
                'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError',
                'location': 2,
                'expectedType': {
                    'prim': 'pair',
                    'args': [{
                        'prim': 'key_hash',
                        'annots': ['%destination']
                    }, {
                        'prim': 'mutez',
                        'annots': ['%amount']
                    }],
                    'annots': [':proposition']
                },
                'wrongExpression': {
                    'prim': 'Pair',
                    'args': [{
                        'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                    }, {
                        'int': '2000000'
                    }]
                }
            }, {
                'kind': 'permanent',
                'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.invalidConstantTypeError',
                'location': 3,
                'expectedType': {
                    'prim': 'key_hash'
                },
                'wrongExpression': {
                    'string': 'KT1CY4g5MTxwyfC7zT5eju8FkdgmnGgHF5Qj'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}],
'signature': 'edsigtu9rtsMXF9GeMTu9QCwWeNMLmsn8BMMkcMVRPuLD9mtNAQSmPuMvNBvuXza4sygyxT9KGjsWyBNsEpVGB8mg8t5mUShekk'
}]
```

Could someone tell me how to transfer from a KT1 address to another KT1 address? After all, the application only exists for the scenario: transfer XTZ between 2 multisign KT1 address.

hope Ocaml Pro can answer. because the example mulitisig.liq can't send to another KT1 address

Answer (score 1):

The liquidity multisig example you used can only send to a key_hash as per the smart contract code. This means that this multisig contract can not send to a KT1 address (which is an originated address).

You can do this using Michelson smart contracts, I have written a basic example in fi: https://github.com/TezTech/tzcontracts/blob/master/multi_sig/basic.fi

This contract can be compiled to Michelson at https://fi-code.com. We will be putting together more documentation regarding this and an example of how you can send and receive from it, but feel free to use the online editor and documentation too.

Comment: hi stephen, could you please expand on your response to fully answer the question ? it looks more like a comment according to SE :)

Comment: 1:   I found a KT1 address   KT1XfTzTJWFMsEukKXXVoKbwsBFbZvYS3hkn  has no code. what meaning of this address, just for delegate?   2: if a KT1 address has michelson code. send to it must need parameter right?

Answer (score -1):

In the error, you can see

```
'kind': 'permanent',
'id': 'proto.003-PsddFKi3.badContractParameter',
'contract': 'KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4'
```

This is because `KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4` is not a contract with type parameter unit (https://alphanet.tzscan.io/KT1DKT2QpnwNnRCzVnYYuwuZuuS2AAajHBC4?default=code), so the internal `TRANSFER_TOKENS` with `Unit` fails.